# How to show compact style input Choice set options(radio buttons) in single line?

Tags: node.js, radio-button, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I am using adaptive card version 1.2.6 for MS Teams bot integration. As per my UI Requirements, I need to display compact style choice set options in a single line. But adaptive card designers displaying horizontally. Is it possible to show options in a single line(vertically)?

Design JSON:

```
{
    "spacing": "Small",
    "id": "leave_duration",
    "placeholder": "Leave Duration",
    "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
    "style": "expanded",
    "isMultiSelect": true,
    "choices": [
        {
            "title": "First Half",
            "value": "First Half"
        },
        {
            "title": "Second Half",
            "value": "Second Half"
        },
        {
            "title": "Full Day",
            "value": "Full Day"
        }
    ],
    "separator": true
}
```

Comment: So you want to show the 3 choices in one line , we're not talking about the dropdown option are we? As far as i know this is not possible at least not with a single choiceSet. You would have to use columns and 1 choiceSet in each column to get what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want to show as items in single choiceSet. Is it possible?